# ruby method is acting as instance method as well as class method

Tags: ruby

In irb console I have created one class 'Hello'

```
irb(main):001:0> class Hello
irb(main):002:1> end
=> nil
```

and created one method outside of 'Hello' class with name 'hi'

```
irb(main):003:0> def hi
irb(main):004:1> 'hiiii'
irb(main):005:1> end
=> :hi
```

Now this hi method is acting as class method as well as instance method

```
irb(main):006:0> Hello.hi
=> "hiiii"
irb(main):007:0> Hello.new.hi
=> "hiiii"
irb(main):008:0> hi
=> "hiiii"
```

why this hi method is get invoke using class 'Hello' even though it is outside of 'Hello' class context ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Methods defined in the "main" context (i.e. not within a class or module declaration) are defined on Object. Since every class, including (big-C) Class, inherits from Object, the method then exists in the inheritance chain of every object and every class. You can observe the same behavior by defining a method explicitly on Object:

```
class Object
  def foo
    puts "Hello"
  end
end

class Bar; end

Bar.foo
# => Hello

Bar.new.foo
# => Hello

foo
# => Hello
```

Comment: There is another thing at play here. Methods defined at the top-level become *private* instance methods of `Object`, which means that both of those calls *should* raise an exception "private method called". **But** IRb (and *only* IRb) behaves differently from Ruby in this regard and makes them public. So, this works if and only if you try it in IRb.